# why num equal zero ever when i click increase and decrease also return zero when it toasts inside it equal the num

Tags: java, android, arrays, variables, int

Why is `num = 0` after every click on *increase* or *decrease*? The method `increasedecrease(...)` always returns `0` but inside the `OnClickListner` it changes its value to the real number. Can anyone please explain this behaviour?

```
int num;

public int incraesedecrease( final titleHodler viewHolder) {

    viewHolder.increase.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            num = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.textnum.getText().toString());
            num++;
            String txtnum = Integer.toString(num);
            viewHolder.textnum.setText(txtnum);
        }
    });

    viewHolder.decrease.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            num--;
            String txtnum=Integer.toString(num);
            if(num>0) {
                viewHolder.textnum.setText(txtnum);
            }

        }
    });

    Toast.makeText(context, ""+num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return num;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't the second `onClick` also start with the statement `num=Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.textnum.getText().toString());`?

Comment: ya it solved this statment will be in the top not in first or second

Comment: This edit improves language in a few aspects, those are punctuation and the exchange of certain parts of the sentences in order to be more precise concerning the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the method you are simply creating onclick listeners. The value returned by the method should be same as the initial value just before calling the function.

The line Toast and return are executed when the function increasedecrease is called and not when button is clicked.